# How to draw a line on a buttons on android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an I/O game . i would like to draw line when a player won [image]

i tried using canvas but it displays the straight over another background 
with this code . can someone help me pleaze  `

```
    DrawView drawView = new DrawView(MainActivity.this);

    setContentView(drawView);
}
 public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint =new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context cn){

        super(cn);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(8);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas cn){

        cn.drawLine(200,200,600,700,paint);
    }

}`
```

Comment: You can change colors of buttons in a line, (for Winner), blink colors of buttons.

Comment: it works but it does not look good , i wanna make something modern

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make custom draw views you can easily implemented that from your xml use relative first put your usual button after button just put a simple view with background as black

```
<Relativelayout>
<Button/>
<View width="yourwidth" height="1dp" background="black">
</Relativelayout>
```

Now to show and hide any line just set it's visibility to visible invisible as per your need

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem using :

```
<FrameLayout>
<Buttons/>
<ImageView android:translationZ="90dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```